# See all of iOS 7 simulator in Xcode 5 on non-retina Macbook

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I am trying to test an app in the simulator (3.5 retina iPhone) and am running into a bit of an annoyance. I can't see the bottom 10th of the screen...

I have tried the Cmd+3 shortcut but unfortunately that part of the screen is still missing. For example, the card should be in the middle of the screen below:

[image]

For this app, I have some components at the bottom of the screen that I can't see in the simulator. For now, I'm having to move the components further up the screen so that I can test them but it isn't ideal.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have designed your view for the 4 inch display, and have not set up autolayout/springs and struts to layout your view correctly.

Comment: You are quite right, my layout isn't configured correctly. It all makes sense now!